# nohup npm start terminated

Tags: node.js, linux, nohup

I am trying to run my reactjs project on background with this command.

`nohup npm start > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

output should be redirected and nohup means do not terminate process when the stty is cut off.
However my npm node is not running at all. this is from nohup log.

```
Starting the development server...

events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EBADF: bad file descriptor, read
Emitted 'error' event on ReadStream instance at:
    at internal/fs/streams.js:202:14
    at FSReqCallback.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:528:5) {
  errno: -9,
  code: 'EBADF',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever). you can check more advanced scenarios from the link. below is the simplest way of using it

```
sudo npm install forever -g
```

then

```
forever start app.js
```

Comment: import React, { Component } from 'react';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module, 
when using forever